# titanium mobile, release memory with memorypool

Tags: javascript, android, memory-leaks, titanium-mobile

I am trying to find a solution to release the memory on android using memorypool function I found another day. My problem is that I am not sure how to implement it. How to call that function and how to pass the window.children object in it. Here is the original function I found:

```
var MemoryPool = function() {
    var _window;
    /*
     Here we make our "auto-release" pool. It's simply a window.
     We hide it upon creation so it won't interfere with our view hierarchy.

     5/3/2011: It seems that the window does not need to be a subcontext, just a regular window will do.
     */
    this.init = function() {
        _window = Ti.UI.createWindow();
        _window.hide();
        _window.open();
    }
    // This is where we clear out the memPool by closing it then reopening it again.
    this.clean = function(obj) {
        if(obj instanceof Array) {
            var arLen=obj.length;
            for ( var i=0, len=arLen; i<len; ++i ) {
                // We then stick the entire view into the pool
                _window.add(obj[i]);
            }
        } else {
            // We then stick the entire view into the pool
            _window.add(obj);
        }
        Ti.API.info('Cleaning MemoryPool.');

        // We empty the pool by closing it.
        _window.close();

        // We recreate the window again for the next object
        this.init();
    };
    this.init();
}
```

Lets say I have a simple window and a few children in it. Shell I just call MemoryPool at the begining or I need to pass something into it like MemoryPool(obj)

Thank you if someone has better idea of it.